# Error in Unit Test MVC Controller using Fake

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, controller

I am trying to do Unit Testing of MoviesContrller. Controller is created as below,

```
  public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMovieRepository db;

    public MoviesController(IMovieRepository db)
    {
        this.db = db;

    }

  public ActionResult Index(string movieGenre, string searchString, string BinderList)
    {



        var movies = db.GetAllMovies();

        return View(movies);
    }
   }
   }
```

To do unit testing of Index action, I have created FakeRepository as below,

```
  public class FakeMovieRepository : IMovieRepository
     {

        public bool WasGetAllMoviesCalled { private set; get; }

        public IQueryable<Movie> GetAllMovies()
           {
            WasGetAllMoviesCalled = true;
            List<Movie> lstMovies = new List<Movie>
                {
                    new Movie
                    {
                        Rating = "PG",
                        ID = 1,
                        Title = "When Harry Met Sally",
                        Price = 7.99M,
                        Genre = "Romantic Comedy",
                        ReleaseDate = Convert.ToDateTime("1/11/1989 12:00:00 AM")
                    }
                };

             return lstMovies as IQueryable<Movie>;

  }
  }
```

I have written Unit Test on Index action as below,

```
  [TestMethod]
    public void ReturnAllMoviesGivenEmptyStringParameters()
    {

       //Arange 
        FakeMovieRepository repo = new FakeMovieRepository();
        var  moviesController = new MoviesController(repo);


        //Actual
        var result = moviesController.Index(String.Empty, String.Empty,String.Empty ) as     ViewResult;

        // returning null always :(  on debigging found that calling fake repo function but returning null !
        var movies = result.Model as IQueryable<Movie>;

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(true, repo.WasGetAllMoviesCalled);

    }
```

As you see in the comment that always result.model returns null whereas WasGetAllMoviesCalled get returns as true. I put a breakpoint to debug test.

[image: BreakPoint on Index]

Db.GetAllMovies() returns List of Movie. But to my surprise values of movies is always null. I am sure I am doing something stupid here. Keep in mind that db.GetAllMovies() is calling GetAllMovies function of FakeMovieRepository. Ideally movies should contain List of movies returned from db.GetAllMovies()

Any help on same? How to unit test controller without using mock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List< T >  doesn't implement IQueryable< T >.

Look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the definition of method GetAllMovies. So it will be repo.GetAllMethods = ()=>{ return new List<>();